# Problem with getting comments, replies and child replies of post

Tags: php, laravel

Making app like miniinstagram where We have recommendations(posts) and users which can comment them . Getting data through api. And have problem with getting all comments and all replies of certain post .

I have a db table

```
comment
-------------------------------
|id                           |
|text(comment text)           |
|recommendation_id(post_id)   |
|user_id(author)              |
|parent_id(parent comment id) |
-------------------------------
```

Here  in parent_id we can set parent comment id . Comments have replies and replies also have replies . 
Here Comment model

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['user:id,name'];
    protected $table = 'comments';
    protected $fillable = ['text','user_id','recommendation_id'];



    public function recommendation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MobileApp\Recommendation' , 'recommendation_id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MobileApp\Comment' ,'parent_id');
    }
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MobileApp\Comment' ,'id');
    }
}
```

and 
Recommendation model

```
class Recommendation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'recommendations';
    protected $fillable = ['course_id','title','description','file'];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MobileApp\Comment')->where('parent_id', '=', Null);
    }
}
```

And here Recommendation controller method index

```
public function index()
    {
        $recommendations = Recommendation::all();
        foreach($recommendations as &$item){
            //changing to full path
            $item['file'] = 'https://example.com/' . $item['file'];
            //getting comments
            $item['comments']=$item->comments;
           //getting replies
            foreach($item->comments as $alphabet => $collection) {
                 $collection->replies;
//if reply array not empty then look for child repliese. I should have here recursive 
                    if($item->comments[$alphabet]->replies->count()>0){
                    foreach($item->comments[$alphabet]->replies as $alphabet => $collection) {
                        $collection->replies;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        if ($recommendations)
        {
            $response = ['success'=>true, 'data'=>$recommendations];
        }
        else
            $response = ['success'=>false, 'data'=>'Record doesnt exists'];


        return $response;
    }
```

The problem is if Im getting not empty reply then I must look for child replies .  I should have something like recursive . How can I do this ?

UPD:
Hello. I added setting likes function to posts , comments and replies. And have some problems.   I have "Like" table which is have ['user_id','likeobject_id']. It is many to many relation between Comment and User .I have added to Comment model

```
public function CommentLikesCount()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','likes' ,'likeobject_id','user_id')->withPivot('likeobject')->where('likeobject', '=', 2);
}
```

Here likeobject is just mean it is comment not post . It doesnt matter .
And added to User model

```
public function CommentLikes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\MobileApp\Comment','likes' ,'user_id','likeobject_id')->withPivot('likeobject')->where('likeobject', '=', 2);
}
```

Then added to

```
 foreach ($recommendation->comments as $comment) {
        $comment->loadRecursiveReplies();

        $comment['comment_likes']=$comment->CommentLikesCount->count();

    }
```

But it shows likes count only for first comment . For parent comment . Not for Replies .

I added this  . But it doesnt work.

```
public function loadReplies() {
    return $this->load('replies.CommentLikesCount');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be something like this:

**Controller:**

```php
    ...

    public function index()
    {
        $recommendations = Recommendation::with([
            'comments.user',
            'comments.replies.user'
        ])->paginate(10);

        foreach ($recommendations as $item) {

            foreach ($item->comments as $comment) {
                // I have moved your code to load `replies` in model
                $comment->loadRecursiveReplies();
            }

        }

        if (!$recommendations->isEmpty()) {
            $response = ['success' => true, 'data' => $recommendations->toArray()];
        } else {
            $response = ['success' => false, 'data' => 'Record doesnt exists'];
        }


        return $response;
    }

    ...
```

**Comment Model:**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
     // All the code that loads replies recursively is here...
     ...

     public function isRepliesLoaded() {
          return isset($this->relations['replies']);
     }

     public function loadReplies() {
          return $this->load('replies.user');
     }

     public function loadRecursiveReplies()
     {
        if (!$this->isRepliesLoaded()) {
            $this->loadReplies();
        }

        if ($this->replies->isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($this->replies as $reply) {
            $reply->loadRecursiveReplies();
        }
    }

     ...
}
```

**Recommendation Model:**

```
class Recommendation extends Model
{
    ...
    // This will prepend site url in your file path when you access with `$this->file` automatically.
    public function getFileAttribute($value) {
        return 'https://example.com/' . $value;
    }
    ...
}
```

**PS:** *This code is not tested.*

Comment: It works like a charm  on the first try . You are genius. Thank you for your time. I will learn your code to do it right on next time . Thanks

Comment: Happy to help you @Rock :)

Comment: Hello. I added Likes function to your code and have some problems. Can you please give me idea how to solve it ?

Comment: @Rock - Post a new question and link this post. I or someone from `stackoverflow` will help you. It's not right to answer multiple question in a single thread.